# is there a maximum size limit on the root drive while creating a new EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

say, if I setup a windows server 2012 instance, is there a maximum size limit on the C drive?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question for Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With Amazon EBS, you can...Create storage volumes up to 1 TB in size and attach them as devices on EC2 instances.

[Source.](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/)

Comment: looks like the concept of root drives and file systems simply don't apply for EBS - which is great. thanks for your clear answer and the source.